# Javascript/Jquery JSON File Upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, web

I have to create a html list with one `li` name  **import** . On back i have create `input type ="file"` which will be **hidden** .

If user click on **import**  it should fire file upload from back using `.click()`[![enter image description here][1]][1].

Once the use select the .`json` file it can be of any name ..

Then On click of **open button** of file upload it should save the `json` and pass the `json` object with an event dispatcher . I have create event dispatcher but not able to get `json`

Issue : I am not able to save the json object using `.onChange` and also `.onChange` work single time then i have to refresh then it work again.

Requirement: On click of **import button**, hidden file **import** will fire then on selecting the json file of any name (json filem can be of any name) function will save the json object and json object will be sent using iframe using event dispatcher . 
Issue:: Not able to save the json or get the json . I tried `getjson` but it if for single file name .

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('button').click(function (){

     $('#import').click();




    });


$('#import').on('change',function () {

  // not able to get json in a json object on selection of json file 
 var getJson = $('#import')[0].files;


// dispatcher just take json object and it will send to iframe . 

  // WindowDispatcher("Send Json", getJson);

 });

 });
</script>
</head>

<body>
<input type='file' id='import' style = "display:none" accept='.json ' aria-hidden="true" >
<ul>
<li>
<button id="importLink" >import</button>
</li>
</ul>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please don't post images of your code, it's way better to post the actual code itself.

Comment: It seems like you want to read the JSON of a file chosen using a file input. As such you don't need AJAX, but a FileReader: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23344776/519413

Comment: On change work once then i have to reload the page to make it work again..

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#importLink").click(function(){
      $("#import").click();   
   });
   function readTextFile(file, callback) {
    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.overrideMimeType("application/json");
    rawFile.open("GET", file, true);
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (rawFile.readyState === 4 && rawFile.status == "200") {
            callback(rawFile.responseText);
        }
    }
    rawFile.send(null);
}
    $("#import").on('change',function(e){
      var file =  e. target. files[0];
      var path = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(file);
readTextFile(path, function(text){
    var data = JSON.parse(text);
    console.log(data);
    //Your ajax call here.
      });
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="import" style="display:none" accept='.json' aria-hidden="true" >
<ul>
 <li id="importLink">import</li>
 </ul>
 <output id="list"></output>
 <div id="name">list</div>
  <div id="age">list</div>
```

Read file from `e. target. files[0];`

Comment: { 
  "first_name"  :  "hello", 
  "last_name"   :  "work", 
  "online"      :  true 
}

Answer (score 0):

Off what I can see, you are missing an argument list for your import onChange listener.

In the first image, you are calling `$'#import').click()` -- you are missing the leading `(`

you should be getting a javascript error when running the code you mentioned, since you don't include at least an empty argument list when the file input changes, though I could be wrong.

Comment: yes i fixed it .. share the code also.. now how to get json i m not sure

Comment: ReferenceError: WindowDispatcher is not defined