# Loading local json file with require?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, require

I've been googling for hours now, thought I just ask here. For some reason my 'require()' does not work. The recuirejs is included and as far as I can see my return value should be my data in the exact same order as my json file.

here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(async function() {
  let data = await fetchData('./data/file.json');
  console.log(data);
}
// fetch and return data
function fetchData(path) {
  return require([path]);
}
```

I originally had this solution (which worked with a local host but I need it without a host):

```
function fetchData(path) {
  return fetch(path).then(response => {
    return response.json().then((data) => {
      return data;
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    })
  });
}
```

It gives me several script errors and MIME type mismatches plus it logs this instead of my data:

```
s(e, t, i)
​   arguments: null
   caller: null
​  >defined: function defined(e)
​   isBrowser: true
   length: 3
   name: "s"
​  >prototype: Object { … }
  >specified: function specified(e)​
  >toUrl: function toUrl(e)​
  >undef: undef(i)
```

I don't know what else I should try.

Thank you!

Comment: if it's just a JSON File, you can load it with [fs.readFile](https://nodejs.dev/learn/reading-files-with-nodejs) and parse it with [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Comment: @RenéDatenschutz — the Node.js `fs` module is not available in browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RequireJS is not compatible with Node.js's require method. It is designed for [AMD modules](https://auth0.com/blog/javascript-module-systems-showdown/#Asynchronous-Module-Definition--AMD-) not [CommonJS modules](https://auth0.com/blog/javascript-module-systems-showdown/#CommonJS) and it does not support the loading of plain JSON files. This is why your first attempt does not work.

Your second attempt does not work because [file systems requests are treated as cross-origin requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752055/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-error-when-loading-a-local).

The only way to load a JSON file when working on the load filesystem is to have the user select it with an `<input type="file">` and then [read it with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23344776/how-to-access-data-of-uploaded-json-file/27116209#27116209).

If you want to read hard-coded JSON then you might consider baking it into your app. The simple way to do that would be to just paste it in as a JS object literal. More complex programs might benefit from using a tool like [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) (which would need a [JSON loader](https://v4.webpack.js.org/loaders/json-loader/)) and pulling it into the JS at build-time rather than development time (the aforementioned pasting approach) or run time (which is impossible as mentioned in previous paragraphs).

Answer (score -1):

You have two options:

- Use a tool like Webpack to put all your frontend files into the bundle
- Download JSON file from web server:

I assume you are using jQuery already, so:

```
$.get('https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json').then(function(data) {
  console.log(data.swagger);
});
```

In this case you have to make your json file available for webserver

```
$.get('/dist/data/file.json').then(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```