# When form submitted: The character encoding of the html document was not declared (although it is)

Tags: html

I've seen a few questions relating to this, but almost all of them use `php`. I have just a simple html file, with an input and a button. I've tried using proposed solutions, but I always get the error after I submit the form with the button. I have included the character enconding as `utf-8`. I also have the `<meta charset="utf-8" />` but commented out upon seeing other solutions on SO, which I have implemented to no avail.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <script src="index.js"></script>
    <title>My Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="data-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        <input type="file" id="file-input">
        <button id="form-btn" type="submit">Load File</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Based on my rudimentary understanding, this should read the file no problem. I'm trying to upload a JSON file, not sure if that's the issue. It is a valid JSON, I have checked and double-checked.

The `index.js` file that is linked, currently does not interact with the file upload in anyway, so in the interest of brevity I have not included it.

### EDIT

I "solved" this, I guess. More like bypassed it. I wrote a JS function (`readFile()`) to read on click, and changed the button's type to `type="button"` and put an `onclick="readFile()"` and now it reads the file and eecutes properly. Hopefully maybe this will help someone else who has a similar problem. I guess this can be closed.

Comment: Where do you get the error? Browser console? Form handler? Do you need an `action` attribute on the form or do you send it via JavaScript?

Comment: Yes, it shows up in the console. I don't send it with JS (at least not yet) so maybe I do need an `action` attr. I will read the MDN docs and see if that leads to enlightenment.

Comment: If you don't send the form via JS how can that error show up in the browser console? The network tab can also be very helpful.

Comment: I have no idea, if I did I probably wouldn't be here asking the question. The javascript file does nothing at the moment because none of the functions are "plugged in" to the `index.html`.  If I change the button `type="button"` I don't get an error, but also nothing happens. I'm not sure if that's better or worse.

Comment: Well I'm just asking to make you understand it yourself. Seems you solved your problem. 

Answer (score 0):

See edit. I used a modified version of the IFFE answer posted in this question [How to access data of uploaded JSON file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23344776/how-to-access-data-of-uploaded-json-file). I'm not sure if this is "technically" the solution but it works for my purposes.